# iOS SDK library which allows the user to draw on screen and save as an image?

Tags: ios, image, cocoa-touch

Are there any iOS libraries which give a custom control where users can draw on the screen, and it can be exported as an image file?

Comment: Jason : Have you got some solution , i also need the same.

Answer (score 6):

Below are some Open Source Projects I've found on Github.

- [Painter](https://github.com/edwardinubuntu/Painter)
- [Paint-App](https://github.com/oflannabhra/Paint-App)
- [Cloud Finger Paint Client](https://github.com/Atrac613/CloudFingerPaint-Client-iOS)

In terms of Libraries or Frameworks, here is one from CocoaControls (which by the way has a whole collection of Cocoa stuff for OSX and iPhone)

- [Smooth Line View](http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/smooth-line-view)

You could incorporate the [GLPaint](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GLPaint/Introduction/Intro.html) code that Apple provides or use some of the code in the [QuartzDemo](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/QuartzDemo/Introduction/Intro.html) Demo Application. You could create a simple application just using the touch methods and UIBezierPaths on a view.

Comment: FWIW, I found Smooth Line View to be a great project. It's very minimal, elegant, and performant. I even forked it and submitted back a pull request just now. :)